# react-syntax-highlighter not beautifying code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, dom-events, pretty-print

I am using the package "react-syntax-highlighter" to beautify code in react project, but somehow it still doesn't work as expected. I tried to search similar issues, but couldn't found any solution. Below `{codeString}` is generated by using blockly (by google).

```
<SyntaxHighlighter language="javascript" style={docco} showLineNumbers>
      {codeString}
</SyntaxHighlighter>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @SurjithSM apparently I need to use another package for formatting "js-beautify" 
```window.js_beautify {codeString} ```, where the js_beautify is the variable that you set

Answer (score 1):

a few things to consider:

[image]

Make sure backticks are gonna be on the left edge. do not tab it. and use the language shorthand right after the first ```js as above.

Answer (score 1):

### It doesn't beautify code.

As I investigated, [`react-syntax-highlighter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-syntax-highlighter) works as intented, it never says about formatting at all, it's only a highlighter or colorizer.

**You have to use a separate library**, i.e. [`prettier`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier). They will not conflict since `prettier` is just putting tabs, spaces and breaks right into the string.

Answer (score -2):

### For beautify code in *react-syntax-highlighter* you can use *prettier*

#### Example:

[image]

#### Output :

[image]